# How can i strip namespaces and xml version during JsonConvert

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, json.net

Is there a way to via JsonConvert or any other function to return a clean Json Object without the XML and Name Spaces ? I have a websercice that gets data from a remote Soap Service and i give the user the option to either get the data in XML or Json. The XML which i get look like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ADDR_VAL_RESP xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM">
        <HDR>
            <MESSAGE_ID>FROMCLIENTAPPLET</MESSAGE_ID>
            <MSG_TIMESTAMP>2020-03-11T16:24:07</MSG_TIMESTAMP>
            <TXNUM>temP</TXNUM>
            <DTSENT>202003110424PM</DTSENT>
        </HDR>
        <RESP_STATUS_GRP>
            <RESPC>003</RESPC>
            <RESPD>Address Match Found</RESPD>
        </RESP_STATUS_GRP>
        <ATT_ADDR_INFO>
            <FEP>X</FEP>
            <SVC_ADDR_GRP>
                <SANO>818</SANO>
                <SASD>W</SASD>
                <SASN>7TH</SASN>
                <TAR>001</TAR>
            </SVC_ADDR_GRP>
        </ATT_ADDR_INFO>
    </ADDR_VAL_RESP>
</ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP>
```

When i convert this to JSON it looks like this..

```
{
    "?xml": {
        "@version": "1.0"
    },
    "ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP": {
        "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "ADDR_VAL_RESP": {
            "@xmlns": "http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM",
            "HDR": {
                "MESSAGE_ID": "FROMCLIENTAPPLET",
                "MSG_TIMESTAMP": "2020-03-11T16:28:50",
                "TXNUM": "temP",
                "DTSENT": "202003110428PM"
            },
```

But i would like it to look like this

```
 {
       "ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP": {
            "ADDR_VAL_RESP": {
                "HDR": {
                    "MESSAGE_ID": "FROMCLIENTAPPLET",
                    "MSG_TIMESTAMP": "2020-03-11T16:28:50",
                    "TXNUM": "temP",
                    "DTSENT": "202003110428PM"
                }, .....
```

So the question is, is there a way to do this other then taking the xml response a part and remove any extra stuff like name spaces etc and create a new object in return it json encoded.

Comment: Load the XML with a XmlDocument, `dim doc = new XmlDocument() doc.Load([XML])`, then remove the first node:  `doc.RemoveChild(doc.ChildNodes(0))` and `dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)`. If this is what you mean.

Comment: You could add `doc.FirstChild.Attributes.RemoveAll()` if you don't deserialize the JSON to a class structure. Or `for each childNode as XmlNode in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes childNode.Attributes.RemoveAll() next` to remove other attributes from child XmlNodes (add recursion if you need to go deeper).

Comment: i am more concerned about removing the name spaces like "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Comment: Yes that did the trick.. You want to post it as answer so i can accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

The source XML file or string can be parsed in many different ways. I choose the [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) class since it's simple to use and directly compatible with the JSON serializer.

The XML has two elements:
- A prolog that defines the XML version (but not the encoding: UTF-8 is assumed)
- A Root element (`ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP`), which contains Attributes that need to be removed when the XML is converted to a JSON format.

The [XmlDocument.Load()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load) or [XmlDocument.LoadXml()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml) methods can be used to generate XML Document object.
- The former expects a Stream or a string that represents a Path to a file (or a Xml/Text Reader)
- The latter only parses XML strings

Assuming it's a Stream, we can generate the XmlDocument using its `Load()` method:

```
Dim doc = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load([XML Stream])  
' or doc.Load([XML File Path])
' or doc.LoadXml([XML String])
```

To remove the prolog element, we can remove the first child Node of the XmlDocument:

```
doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild)
```

Since the Root element (**`ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP`**) needs to be preserved (as in the sample result), while its Attributes should be removed, we can use the [XmlNode.Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes) collection's [RemoveAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.removeall) method to perform the clean-up:

```
doc.FirstChild.Attributes.RemoveAll()
```

If the Root element is not really required, we could also use the [JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode_2.htm) overload that allows to specify whether the Root element should be preserved:

```
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.Indented, True)
```

The last argument specifies that the Root element should be omitted.

The first child Node of the Root element also contains Arguments that need to be removed:

```
For Each childNode As XmlNode in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes
    childNode.Attributes.RemoveAll()
Next
```

All parts combined, using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize the XML to a JSON string:

```
Dim doc = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load([XML Stream])  

' FirstChild is the prolog element
doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild)

' Now FirstChild is the XML Root element
doc.FirstChild.Attributes.RemoveAll()

For Each childNode As XmlNode in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes
    childNode.Attributes.RemoveAll()
Next

' Or RemoveAllAttributes(doc)

Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.Indented)
```

If all child Nodes need to be stripped of their Attributes, a recursive method can be used instead of a loop:

```
RemoveAllAttributes(doc)
(...)

Private Sub RemoveAllAttributes(XmlNode node)
    if node.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then node.Attributes.RemoveAll()
    For Each childNode As XmlNode In node.ChildNodes
        If childNode.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then childNode.Attributes.RemoveAll()
        If childNode.HasChildNodes Then
            RemoveAllAttributes(childNode)
        End if
    Next
End Sub
```